# How to get data from Xamarin.Droid to ViewModel in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.droid

I'm making an app for some research. I'm trying to listen to all of the wifi networks, and save them in a database. But I need to save more information then just the wifi details.
I'm using Xamarin Forms for a cross platform solution.
What I already have that's working:
    - A View that is binding with the ViewModel.
    - The ViewModel is working as predicted, withe the values of the entries that I've created in the View.
    - The project MySolution.Droid has code that accesses the wifi networks. 
    - I have a Receiver that is firing OnReceive with the information.

What I've done that might not be the best choice:
    - Since after starting scan I'm waiting (async) for the OnReceive to fire. I've chosen to send the data to the ViewModel via MessagingCenter.
    - I'm sending with success the information. And receiving it in the ViewModel with MessagingCenter.Subscribe

What's wrong:
    - I can't get the information out (into my ViewModel), every property that the ViewModel has is null. 
    - What I'd like is to just get the information to the ViewModel. Or if I could just get the information that is binding to the View in the BeginInvokeOnMainThread, that wold work just fine.

The code that I have:

ScanViewModel.cs:

```
    string locationName;
    public string LocationName
    {
        get
        {
            return locationName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (locationName != value)
            {
                locationName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                StartScanCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
            }
        }
    }
    public ScanViewModel()
        {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<IScanReceiver, List<ScanResult>>(this, "receiveWiFiNetworks", (sender, arg) =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
                async () =>
                {
                    var l = LocationName // THIS IS NULL
                    ......
                }
                );
            });
    }
```

App.Droid.Wifi.cs:

```
    public void GetWifiNetworks()
    {
        WiFiNetworks = new List<ScanResult>();

        wifi = (WifiManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);

        wifiReceiver = new WifiReceiver();
        context.RegisterReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.ScanResultsAvailableAction));
        wifi.StartScan();
    }

    class WifiReceiver : BroadcastReceiver, IScanReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            List<ScanResult> scanwifinetworks = wifi.ScanResults.ToList();

            MessagingCenter.Send<IScanReceiver, List<ScanResult>>(this, "receiveWiFiNetworks", scanwifinetworks);
        }
    }
```

For those who didn't read the post above (like, tldr), I'm receiving the list of ScanResult in the OnReceive and I need it to be in the ViewModel, But I also need the rest of the properties...

If there's a simpler way of doing this, I'm all ears!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: LocationName is null because it's not filled anywhere. Where did you assign a value to LocationName?

Comment: @Vahid, It's binded in the View, And it has value, because there is a Command that need it to not be null to fire. As shown above, on change the is a reevaluation of the CanExecute of the Command. And it works, making the resto fire.

Comment: @Jason, I've removed that part (.....), because it's what I'm doing and the list has valid data. I, just need to access the properties of the ViewModel. Or Get this list to the thread in which the Properties have values. (I think...)

Comment: use the debugger to verify that LocationName is getting set when you think that it is

Comment: A point: At the time that your Android class sends a message to your PCL viewmodel, the view must be already filled with a value so that LocationName not be null.

Comment: @Vahid, the LocationName is filled before the message is received. Because there is a button that starts the WiFi scan. That button is executed only if the !isNullOrWhitespaces(LocationName)

Comment: @Jason, I’ve used breakpoints to follow the values. Inside the action inside BeginInvokeOnMainThread it’s null. Do you know a different method of getting the values? :/

Comment: are you sure you just have one instance of your VM?  Are you sure nothing else is resetting the LocationName value?  Try putting a Console.Writeline in the setter so you can see every time that it's set is called

Comment: @Jason, I have a breakpoint in the get and set of LocationName, It only stops when I'm loading the View (get), write in the <entry (set). And when I enter the "Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread" action, it stops (get) to get the value of Location, but it's already null. I'm thinking of the possibility that it creates a new instance or new thread of the ViewModel. The question is: Can I access the previous Thread/instance or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: without seeing more code I can't really tell what might be wrong

Comment: @Jason, what might you need?

Comment: probably the page that instantiates the VM

Comment: I found a solution, populating the local List<ScanResult> in Wifi.cs. And using a Timer, getting that List. It's not very eficient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I found for my problem.

It might not be the best or cleanest way to do it, but it works for now.

In the Wifi.cs class I fill a List

```
    public List<ScanResult> GetWifiNetworks(){
        return WiFiNetworks;
    }

    class WifiReceiver : BroadcastReceiver, IScanReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            WiFiNetworks = wifi.ScanResults.ToList();
        }
    }
```

And I periodically get the list with a Get Method from the ViewModel as follows,

```
    void StartScan()
    {
        Timer _wifiAsyncTimer = new Timer();
        _wifiAsyncTimer.Elapsed += GetWifiNetworks;
        _wifiAsyncTimer.Interval = ListenPeriodicity * 1000;
        _wifiAsyncTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void GetWifiNetworks(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var wifiNetworks = _wifiManager.GetWifiNetworks();
        if (wifiNetworks.Count > 0)
        {
            LocationInformation LocationInformation = new LocationInformation()
            {
                LocationName = LocationName,
                Temperature = Temperature,
                Notes = Notes,
                Timestamp = DateTime.Now
            };
            LocationInformations = LocationInformation.AddWifiInformation(wifiNetworks);
        }
    }
```

With this, I can access all the Information and the properties aren't null.

If anybody has a better solution, I'm still all ears!!!!!